# Can You Securely Authenticate A Request Via IP?

Tags: php, security, payment-gateway

I am currently integrating the NAB Transact payment gateway into a e-commerce shop. Once the payment has been processed the NAB Transact system sends a POST request to our endpoint for us to process the result.

The problem is that the POST request contains no secure hash / token that we can use to post back to the NAB Transact system to authenticate that the request is real and not spoofed. Even worse, the NAB Transact system does not even have a API for any authentication of any information, essentially, very bad security!

Is there a way to securely authenticate these requests? For example, checking that the requests come from a list of known IP addresses that the NAB transact system operates on? Or reverse lookup a IP? What options are there and how would you implement this in PHP?

Isn't relying on IP authentication not that secure since it can be spoofed?

Comment: You are asking more than one question.  You should create a second question to ask how you should implement authentication.

Comment: No disrespect intended, but this is a job for someone with security experience.  Asking a question like this is a good way to learn about possible solutions and problems, but taking a learn-as-you-go approach to the actual implementation of security is virtually guaranteeing a disaster.

Comment: @adam if you don't have a answer to the question, don't post. the NAB transact is a fully hosted solution with PCI compliance where no data is stored, processed or even entered into our systems. hence why my question is only in regards to post back information from the NAB system, which under their documentation has no means for correct authentication. If i was inexperienced in PCI compliance or security i wouldn't know the problems associated with a request which does not have a secure token and API endpoint for authentication of the request. So it is not learn as you go, this is 5 years exp.

Comment: @cappucino: Does your gateway allow you to include a long unique string in the transaction data so you can at least have a little more evidence that it's a valid postback? How is a transaction initiated? Via a service that your script connects to or is the customer being taken off your site to do the checkout?

Comment: @cappuccino: Comments are meant to comment the question, not to answer it.

Comment: @webbiedave not anything that is not publicly visible i.e. not found in the HTML source. the NAB transact product is a hosted product where information is submitted via a form and there are no options to pass information via a API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the POST request contains no secure hash / token
>   that we can use to post back to the NAB Transact system to
>   authenticate that the request is real and not spoofed

Yup - that's a problem alright :)

> Isn't relying on IP authentication not that secure since it can be
>   spoofed?

It isn't at ALL secure!

Comment: Why not explain how you are going to perform the TCP handshake with a spoofed IP.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication based on IP addresses is fine if you:

- know the list of IPs (i.e. the ones used by the payment provider)
- the IPs are static (obviously, but if the request is actually sent by the provider and not e.g. through a hidden form on the "payment successful" page that's the case)
- they immediately notify you of any changes (or your script might reject valid requests or accept requests from IPs not used by the provider anymore)
- all systems which can use the IP address (i.e. the servers of the payment provider assuming the datacenter is not using some crappy network setup) is trusted enough not to send any false notifications.

Spoofing the source IP is not possible since TCP uses a three-way-handshake and with a spoofed IP the handshake would fail.

So basically: Authentication by IP is acceptable if some basic criteria are met (see above), but of course it would be more secure if they provided you with a way to validate the notification - either by calling an API on their side or by using a cryptographic signature (better since it cannot fail due to an unreachable remote server).

Comment: There are many kinds of TCP/IP spoofing.  Not all of them use the connection setup (the 3-way handshake).  Any ONE of them, if successful, would break security.

Comment: Show me *one* example on how to properly create a **TCP** connection with a spoofed IP.

Comment: Oh, and even though security through obscurity is a very bad thing - how would a potential attacker know the target URL where ths notification request is sent to?

Comment: yeah i spoke with the NAB people again, they have many many ips and it just wouldn't be possible to authenticate with ips, not to mention its not safe. essentially no solutions, who said banks where secure? lol. i'll just have to rely on payment reconciliation.